Why is my website not showing through anything just blank screen even after publishing
enter image description here
the page is not showing anything like icons, text or graphics I have tried everything but still can't figure it out this is my first project could someone please help me.
First, there was some error about gh-pages it got resolved and the site was published but there is nothing on my portfolio site
you can see it here
https://vidhishak15.github.io/portfolio/
The website even after publishing is not showing anything only the background colour .
my App.js code
import './App.scss';
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Layout from './components/Layout';
import Home from './components/Home';
import About from './components/About';
import Contact from './components/Contact';

function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
        <Route index element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
        <Route path="contact" element={<Contact />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  )
}

export default App


Index.html
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"/><link rel="icon" href="favicon.svg"/><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/><meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"/><meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app"/><link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/portfolio/logo192.png"/><link rel="manifest" href="/portfolio/manifest.json"/><title>React App</title><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha256-p4NxAoJBhIIN+hmNHrzRCf9tD/miZyoHS5obTRR9BMY=" crossorigin=""/><script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha256-20nQCchB9co0qIjJZRGuk2/Z9VM+kNiyxNV1lvTlZBo=" crossorigin=""></script><script defer="defer" src="/portfolio/static/js/main.7dc9b3c2.js"></script><link href="/portfolio/static/css/main.17e05163.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript><div id="root"></div><script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@emailjs/browser@3/dist/email.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">emailjs.init("3q1Utfo3iBzn0fhrL")</script></body></html>


Can you post the index.html and main.jsx to have more info about your App

Your router expects URLs like /about/, but since your app is under /portfolio/, that would need to be taken into account.

In your package.json file you have

"homepage": "httlps://VIDHISHAK15.github.io/portfolio-react",

but you publish the page under https://vidhishak15.github.io/portfolio/
"portfolio-react" is not the same as "portfolio".

Update
The part after the vidhishak15.github.io will be the repository name. You cannot specify whatever you want. So in your case it will be portfolio. So https://vidhishak15.github.io/portfolio/
Now this is what you need to add to the package.json file as homepage
"homepage": "https://vidhishak15.github.io/portfolio/"

and that is also what you need to use for the basename property of the BrowserRouter inside you app.
<BrowserRouter basename={"/portfolio"}>

Finally, you need to add some more dependencies to make your project build correctly and then fix the deploy script in package.json (remove the space, otherwise you cannot run the script).

I have changed it but still it is not working

@vidhishakatariya Have you added the basename to the the BrowserRouter ? It should be <BrowserRouter basename={"/portfolio"}>

could you please check my GitHub repo https://github.com/VIDHISHAK15/portfolio.git I am not getting what you are saying .please could you check in the repo .

@vidhishakatariya added an update to the answer.

Hey!thank you for responding, did that but still the webpage is black and not showing anything .The favicon is loading but the content of webpage is not visible

@vidhishakatariya the vercel version seems to be working.

yeah tried on vercel and worked...Thanks!
